# Eclipse - keeping several installations in sync

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to have several installations of Eclipse (with required plugins installed) in sync? If so, what would be the preferred approach?

I am looking for a way to keep Eclipse installations (one on desktop - Wind7 64 bit, another on laptop Win7 64 bit) with the required plugins installed, in sync. Ideally, I would like to exclude the runtime generated files from the sync process. I don't have an exhaustive list of files/folders to exclude but that is the next challenge.

I tried putting one install into a local git repo, then pushing this to a remote repo, followed by cloning from the repo onto the other location. I couldn't launch the cloned instance of Eclipse. I get this error :: http://pastebin.com/BpttUgvG

Versions of interest: Helios, Indigo

I have attempted the following without success

- Start with **eclipse -clean**
- Add -vm option to eclipse.ini file

Any suggestions would be gratefully welcomed.

** EDIT **
Is it possible to do this without having to purchase additional software?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses and apologies for the delay in responding. I had been distracted by a few things and didn't get the time to try out the various suggestions in detail. <BR> I managed to get my own approach working. The issue was in the Git configuration. The configuration I had issues with had been converting EOL characters while checking in. Since I fixed the configuration to not convert EOLs, it has been working for me so far.

Comment: All the answers received look good for installation, I am not sure how well they would handle the scenario of syncing instances post install. To be fair to all, I feel the best option for me is to not accept one answer, but let the audience explore the great suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I use a script to set up my installs the exact same way on multiple computers.  Eclipse comes with the p2 director, which can be used from the command line to install and update plugins.

For example, I download and untar my `eclipse-SDK-I20110607-0800-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz` and then use the director to load my standard set of features:

```
bash$ eclipse/eclipse \
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
-noSplash \
-repository \
http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly,\
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7,\
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo \
-installIUs \
org.eclipse.egit.feature.group,\
org.eclipse.egit.source.feature.group,\
org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group,\
org.eclipse.jgit.source.feature.group,\
org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group,\
org.eclipse.xtext.sdk.feature.group,\
org.eclipse.releng.tools.feature.group
```

The director can also be used to update an install, although non-intuitively by uninstall and then re-installing the same feature in the same call.

**EDIT:**

For a set of IUs you can keep each install up to date using uninstall/re-install in the same director call ... if there's an update available:

```
bash$ eclipse/eclipse \
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director \
-noSplash \
-repository \
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/3.7 \
-uninstallIU org.eclipse.sdk.ide \
-installIU org.eclipse.sdk.ide \
```

I don't think you can use this approach just yet, as you need to avoid [bug 368238](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=368238)

The director won't effect most settings (formatting, keybindings, etc) as they're workspace scoped (INSTANCE)  preferences.  Some like formatting or code templates can be turned into project scoped preferences, and then saved in the SCM with the rest of the project information.  There are hacks as well to copy workspace scoped preferences to every new workspace that you create.

Comment: very interesting suggestion, indeed. I would definitely explore this approach for installations. <br> 2 questions - In addition to installing various components, can this approach be used to set up configuration also? (i.e. Code Formatting, Key shortcuts, Code templates etc). * How can this approach be used to keep the installed instances in sync following the installs (by uninstalling and reinstalling?)? - Say if I added a code snippet to one of my Eclipse instances, could I use p2 director to sync it to the other?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by adding a code snippet.  The director doesn't effect most things within a given workspace, like projects or code/source files.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Read your edit above. Sorry, I meant Code Template when I wrote  "snippet". <br> Note to self: you learnt so much more when you ask questions!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Pulse OneInstall Agent](http://www.poweredbypulse.com/oneinstall_client.php)?  It is meant for this purpose.  They claim that using their tool:

> you and your team can retain configuration records in code
>   repositories (such as CVS), easily update tool configurations and have
>   behind-the-firewall control of your tooling recipes

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise there would be a need to install another software to manage this. I was looking for a simple procedure if that is possible. Installing a paid software to manage a free one seems counter intuitive to me. I shall clarify my post in this context.

Comment: The community edition is free (See http://www.poweredbypulse.com/pulse_products.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple ant script: https://github.com/shajra/provisioning-java to automate the following:

- downloading of eclipse
- install plugins from given update sites
- copy default settings for eclipse and workspace

So you can maintain a single source for your eclipse configuration and automate the install and configuration process.

Comment: Thanks Klaus. This looks like a great approach to install and configure Eclipse installs. In a personal use scenario, where I would prefer to make changes to settings in one Eclipse install (Add a code snippet, change code formatting rules etc) and merge these into the other install, would this technique work?

Answer (score 0):

You know how I do it ? I drop the eclipse install folder in my Dropbox. Boom - absolutely synced*. That is for the same OS. If you want different OSes might work but haven't tried it. Maybe you could setup junctions/hard links to the `plugins`, `features` and `configuration` folders, drop *those* in DB and bug(zilla) them if it doesn't work. Jars should be OS agnostic. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13547674/281545) for my efforts to keep *workspace settings* in sync. See [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1059381/#msg_1059381) for the pecularities of comparing eclipse installs with identical plugins

**EDIT :** you can selective sync out folders in Dropbox - although [there is no easy way to automate it](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/2028/web-interface-for-selective-sync), for a couple computers is not a huge pain

<sub>* : same goes for the firefox profile and this *is* OS agnostic. Same for most of my settings. Gosh if they suspend the free accounts I'll have to pay them</sub>